# Create SensorEvent object using reflecion in Emulator not working

Tags: android, reflection, android-emulator, android-sensors

I want to create a `SensorEvent` object to simulate Sensor data. So i have used this reflection code to create `SensorEvent`

```
private fun getSensorEventObject(size : Int) : SensorEvent?{
    val cons = SensorEvent::class.constructors.toList()
    if (cons.isNotEmpty()) {
        return cons[0].call(size)
    }
    return null
}
```

This is working fine in real device. But when i run this code in Emulator this doesn't work. I got this exception

```
kotlin.reflect.full.IllegalCallableAccessException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class java.lang.Class<kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Constructor> cannot access  method void android.hardware.SensorEvent.<init>(int) of class java.lang.Class<android.hardware.SensorEvent>
```

Not sure, as Emulator don't have real hardware is this the reason i am getting exception.

Is there any way i can create `SensorEvent` object when app is running in Emulator ?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is still marked as package-private.
This can be circumvented by setting it as accessible:

```
private fun getSensorEventObject(size : Int) : SensorEvent?{
    return SensorEvent::class.constructors.firstOrNull()?.let{
        it.isAccessible = true
        it.call(size)
    }
}
```